# I need to modify a table structure and need to find specific columns in database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2000

I need to modify a database and need to find all the tables that contain the column name of 'sysnames'.

I also need to search for views and stored procedures that also contain 'sysnames' in their statements so I can update them accordingly.

This is for SQL2000.

TIA,
DLackey

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somewhat hacky, but you can use these:

```
select *
from information_schema.columns
where column_name = 'sysnames'

select *
from information_schema.views
where view_definition like '%sysnames%'

select *
from information_schema.routines
where routine_definition like '%sysnames%'
```

Comment: Thanks, this appears to be just what I needed.  There was a typo in the last select statement.  I wouldn't have gotten this without your help though.  Thanks.  It should be    
select *
from information_schema.routines
where **routine_definition** like '%sysnames%';

Comment: @dlackey Thanks for the info, copy and paste error. I have corrected my answer.

Answer (score 0):

After posting this, I just noticed the `SQL Server 2000` disclaimer in the question.  I've not run this on SQL Server 2000, so it probably won't work there.

here are two queries which will do what you need:

this will find the column in tables and views, and will give back useful info (ObjectType, DataType, Nullable, etc)

```
SELECT
    s.name as ColumnName
        ,sh.name+'.'+o.name AS ObjectName
        ,o.type_desc AS ObjectType
        ,CASE
             WHEN t.name IN ('char','varchar') THEN t.name+'('+CASE WHEN s.max_length<0 then 'MAX' ELSE CONVERT(varchar(10),s.max_length) END+')'
             WHEN t.name IN ('nvarchar','nchar') THEN t.name+'('+CASE WHEN s.max_length<0 then 'MAX' ELSE CONVERT(varchar(10),s.max_length/2) END+')'
            WHEN t.name IN ('numeric') THEN t.name+'('+CONVERT(varchar(10),s.precision)+','+CONVERT(varchar(10),s.scale)+')'
             ELSE t.name
         END AS DataType

        ,CASE
             WHEN s.is_nullable=1 THEN 'NULL'
            ELSE 'NOT NULL'
        END AS Nullable
        ,CASE
             WHEN ic.column_id IS NULL THEN ''
             ELSE ' identity('+ISNULL(CONVERT(varchar(10),ic.seed_value),'')+','+ISNULL(CONVERT(varchar(10),ic.increment_value),'')+')='+ISNULL(CONVERT(varchar(10),ic.last_value),'null')
         END
        +CASE
             WHEN sc.column_id IS NULL THEN ''
             ELSE ' computed('+ISNULL(sc.definition,'')+')'
         END
        +CASE
             WHEN cc.object_id IS NULL THEN ''
             ELSE ' check('+ISNULL(cc.definition,'')+')'
         END
            AS MiscInfo
    FROM sys.columns                           s
        INNER JOIN sys.types                   t ON s.system_type_id=t.system_type_id and t.is_user_defined=0
        INNER JOIN sys.objects                 o ON s.object_id=o.object_id
        INNER JOIN sys.schemas                sh on o.schema_id=sh.schema_id
        LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.identity_columns  ic ON s.object_id=ic.object_id AND s.column_id=ic.column_id
        LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.computed_columns  sc ON s.object_id=sc.object_id AND s.column_id=sc.column_id
        LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.check_constraints cc ON s.object_id=cc.parent_object_id AND s.column_id=cc.parent_column_id
    WHERE s.name LIKE '%sysnames%'
```

find usages in procedures, functions, and triggers

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    LEFT(s.name+'.'+o.name, 100) AS Object_Name,o.type_desc
    FROM sys.sql_modules        m
        INNER JOIN sys.objects  o ON m.object_id=o.object_id
        INNER JOIN sys.schemas  s ON o.schema_id=s.schema_id
    WHERE m.definition Like '%sysnames%'
    ORDER BY 1
```

Comment: @Martin Smith, yea I noticed that and updated accordingly.  there was no `sql-server-2000` tag at the time.

Comment: Yes I added it based on the last line.

Comment: @KM. The first select statement is giving me a precision error.  The second one is stating:  _Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid object name 'sys.sql_modules'.
Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid object name 'sys.objects'.
Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid object name 'sys.schemas'._

Comment: @KM. just noticed you added the disclaimer to your post.  Thanks for clarifying and I appreciate your help.  I'll definitely keep this in my bag of tricks for when the database is upgraded.